# set chromeCustomTabs visibility to invisible

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

Upon reading the introduction of ChromeCustomTabs, I would like to know if ChromeCustomTabs also support **invisible** view, I would like to have some jobs running in the background.

I know it might be possible in the traditional webview by setting `webView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Can the pre-render feature do the job in this case? (load the page content without displaying it)